# Apache Geode RegionExistsException

Tags: gemfire, geode

In the Pivotal Native Client I've setup a method to read and write a Geode cache region as follows:

```
public void GeodePut(string region, string key, string value) 
{
    CacheFactory cF = CacheFactory.CreateCacheFactory();
    Cache c cF.Create();

    RegionFactory rF = c.CreateRegionFactory(RegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY);
    IRegion<string, string> r = rF.Create<string, string>(region);

    r[key] = value;

    cache.Close();
}
```

when I call this multiple times I get `RegionExistsException` how do I get around that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is easy.
Add a try-catch block to catch the RegionExistsException, then in the catch segment replace the 'create' method with 'get'.
Change this:  rF.Create
for this: rf.get
This works pretty well using Java, i would post the exact signature of the method you needed but im not using .Net native client.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with the `cache.Close()` command. I no longer use `cache.Close()`